# Download older minimal version of LTS Xubuntu (18.04.0)

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

I need to install Xubuntu 18.04 on some laptops. The current version, 18.04.5,  does not work for me, because it contains the 1.20.x version of Xorg, which has a [known incompatibility with some versions of vnc](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/660). Xubuntu 18.04.0 is bundled with Xorg 1.19.

The problem is that I'm failing to find a proper download link for xubuntu-18.04-desktop. The official mirrors all point to 18.04.5.

Is there an archive page where I could download it?

Answer (score 4):

You could always build it from the netboot ISO

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

You mention you want a minimal system :)

```
[ ] boot.img.gz 2018-04-25 21:23    52M
[ ] ldlinux.c32 2018-04-25 21:23    113K
[ ] mini.iso    2018-04-25 21:23    64M
[ ] netboot.tar.gz  2018-04-25 21:23    52M
[ ] pxelinux.0  2018-04-25 21:23    41K
```

Because of a [grub flaw CVE-2020-10713](https://ubuntu.com/blog/mitigating-boothole-theres-a-hole-in-the-boot-cve-2020-10713-and-related-vulnerabilities); many older ISOs that won't boot on patched systems (ie. all 18.04 release before 18.04.5) were removed in clean up...